# Загрузить файл на сайт, python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Помогите разобраться, нужно загрузить видео на сайт без диалогового окна,
Знаю что это можно сделать через `<input type="file"`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пытался сделать так

`ByfileInput = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/input') StringfilePath = "/Users/video/1.mov" ByfileInput.send_keys(StringfilePath)`

и даже так

```
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/input')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", elem)
ByfileInput = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/input')  
StringfilePath = "/Users/video/1.mov"   
ByfileInput.send_keys(StringfilePath)
```

все четно, selenium будто не видит элемент, вообщем не понимаю.

ошибка:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/input"}
```

ссылка на страницу- [https://www.tiktok.com/upload?lang=ru-RU](https://www.tiktok.com/upload/)

Answer (score 0):

как я понимаю selenium не видит элемент ввода
Пожалуйста, попробуйте это с помощью xpath. Оба должны работать.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="w0-find-product-search-bar-search-field"]')))
element.send_keys("1234")
```

или же

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@class="find-product"]')))
element.send_keys("1234")
```

или же

```
driver.execute_script(("document.getElementById('w0-find-product-search-bar-search-field').value='1234'"))
```

Comment: Это все я уже пробывал, input скрыт , там не за что зацепиться (ну или я просто не могу найти), selenium не видит элемент.

Comment: Ничего не работает, возможно я что-то не правильно делаю